# String match if value matches to any string in a vector

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to create a dataset in this form:

[image]

I am not able to figure out what is wrong with the for-loop and if.

And also is there any other simpler solution to what I am doing in R?

```
equality_vector <- c("CEO", "COO","CTO","CDO","CFO","CTO","CIO")

Position <- c("Retired CEO", "COO/Board member", "Operator")
Role <- c(NA, NA, NA)
position1<- cbind.data.frame(Position, Role)

for(pos in position1$Position)
{
  a <- NA
  for (var in equality_vector) {
  if (grepl(var,pos)) {
  a <- var
}
break
}
position1$Role[position1$Position == pos] <- a
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get the job done.  It avoids one loop (the other loop is hiding in the `map_int` statement.  Most programmers in R will avoid for loops like the plague.  They tend to be very slow in R.  You might want to read up on some of these functions and step through what each is doing.

```
library(tidyverse)
match_positions <- function(position) {
  outer(position, equality_vector,  str_detect) %>% 
    t() %>% 
    as_data_frame() %>% 
    map_int(.f = function(x) {
      tmp <- which(x)
      if(length(tmp) == 0) tmp <- NA_integer_
      tmp
    })
}

df <- data.frame(Position)
df %>% 
  mutate(
    Role = equality_vector[match_positions(Position)]
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be

```r
library(dplyr)

data.frame(Position) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Role = ifelse(any(unlist(lapply(equality_vector, function(x) grepl(x, Position)))),
                       equality_vector[unlist(lapply(equality_vector, function(x) grepl(x, Position)))],
                       NA)) %>%
  data.frame() -> df
df
```

**Output is:**

```
          Position Role
1      Retired CEO  CEO
2 COO/Board member  COO
3         Operator <NA>
```

**Sample data:**

```
equality_vector <- c("CEO", "COO", "CTO", "CDO", "CFO", "CTO", "CIO")
Position <- c("Retired CEO", "COO/Board member", "Operator")
```